# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for abc@xyz.com

Tags: asp.net, email, iis-7, iis-6

I am getting "**Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for abc@xyz.com**" when I try to send the mail using ASP.NET. The site is deployed on IIS7, Windows 2008 server.

**The website was working fine on IIS6 and Windows 2003 Server**. I deployed it on IIS7, 2008 it has started giving me this error.

Has anybody experienced this before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717743/mailbox-unavailable-the-server-response-was-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-error)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. Use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Aahh got it... I got it working :)

Thanks Christopher, your suggesion is correct.

But, finding "Default SMTP Virtual Server" was tricky ;)

Even if you use IIS7 to deploy your web site, you have to open IIS6 Manager to configure SMTP server (why?).

I configured SMTP server as follows to make things work:

1. Open IIS6 Manager using Control Panel --> Administrative Tools.
2. Open SMTP Virtual Server properties.
3. On General tab, Set IP address of
   the Web server instead of "All
   Unassigned".
4. In Access tab, click on Relay
   button, this will open Relay
   Restrictions dialog.
5. In relay computers list, add the
   loopback IP address i.e 127.0.0.1
   and IP address of the Web server, so that they can pass/relay emails through the SMTP server.

Comment: The reason this needs to be managed in IIS 6 is because IIS 7.X doesn't have its own SMTP server component, so it uses IIS 6.

Comment: In my web.config I was referring to my smtp server by the name "localhost".  If I followed step 3, this solution failed; if I omitted step 3 it worked.  Thanks :)

Comment: This also applies to IIS8 and server 2012

Comment: We are using a relay in order to send emails via an account in our Office 365.  Do I still need to install the smtp server in IIS 6 even though we aren't using the web server's smtp server.  This is on a Windows Server 2016 running IIS 10.  Does anyone have any suggestions or a solution for this issue?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved my problem.

Answer (score 20):

herein lies the answer...
[IIS Settings](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2006/04/05/using-localhost-as-mailserver-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-for-xxx/)

IIS-->Default SMTP Virtual Server-->Properties-->Access-->Relay restrictions
just add or exclude the IPs you care about, should resolve the issue.

Comment: where is "Default SMTP Virtual Server"? I am using IIS7. In IIS6 there is "SMTP Virtual Server" but in IIS& it is not?

Answer (score 19):

I was facing the identical problem and followed the (very clearly spelled out) steps in Vinod's reply, however this then created a different error:

**Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed**

I did a bit more digging and poking around and (while I'm not sure why this worked) I solved it by:
- Going back into IIS6.0 management console
- Open SMTP Virtual Server properties
- On General tab, changing the 'IP Address:' setting back to '(All Unassigned)'

Not sure why this works, but hopefully will help out someone facing the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 15):

As a picture is worth a thousand words..

When you find the IIS6 manager (I have found that searching for IIS may return 2 results) go to the SMTP server properties then 'Access' then press the relay button.

Then you can either select all or only allow certain ip's like 127.0.0.1

[image: SMTP Relay]

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Vinod for the well presented answer.

I got the same error as Mick Byrne when I followed the steps above. Turning it back to All Unassigned sorted it but I had to tweak a few other things as well:

- Add the user my site was running under to the users on the Security Tab in SMTP Virtual Server.
- Changed the value in the mailSettings > network > host attribute in my web.config to the specific server IP (for example 192.168.100.120) as opposed to localhost (which was pointing at 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file).

Hope this saves someone a few mins of messing about.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this issue by changing the mail settings in the system.net portion of my web.config:

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="yourserver" defaultCredentials="true"/>
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have Exchange **2010**:

(In my case, the error message didn't contain " for abc@xyz.com")

This shows how to add a receive connector: http://exchangeserverpro.com/how-to-configure-a-relay-connector-for-exchange-server-2010/

But I also needed to perform a step found here: http://recover-email.blogspot.com.au/2013/12/how-to-solve-exchange-smtp-server-error.html

> - Go to Exchange Management Shell and run the command
> - Get-ReceiveConnector "JiraTest" | Add-ADPermission -User "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" -ExtendedRights
>     "ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Recipient"

While working on this, I ran the following on the affected server's PowerShell console until the error went away:

```
Send-MailMessage -From "myemail@server.com.au" -To "myemail@server.com.au" -Subject "Test Email" -Body "This is a test"
```

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to share what caused the error in my case. Spend couple hours to figure this out, so hopefully it will help to save someone some time.

Strangely enough, the error was raised with the `Enable drop directory quota` setting being enabled for the domain.

[image]

I am not the expert and don't know the technical explanation, but unticking the mentioned setting sorted the problem.