# IIS SMTP - The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for outgoing address, Still not working

Tags: iis, smtp

I have read [Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for abc@xyz.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165721/mailbox-unavailable-the-server-response-was-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-for-abcxyz-c) and all of the answers. I have added my IP address via

> IIS-->Default SMTP Virtual Server-->Properties-->Access-->Relay restrictions just add or exclude >the IPs you care about, should resolve the issue.

but it still gives me the error as above. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Windows Sever 2003 R2 and IIS6.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I was able to fix this in my case by:

1. Go to Administrative Tools -> IIS 6.0 Manager
2. Right click "SMTP Virtual Server" then Click Properties
3. Select Access tab
4. Click "Relay..." in Relay Restrictions
5. Select "Only the list below"
6. Add 127.0.0.1 and my server IP to the list
7. Check Allow all computers which successfully authenticate to relay, regardless of the list above
8. Click "OK"

Comment: My SMTP server was separate from the web server, so needed to define web server's IP instead.

Comment: For me it was the addition of 127.0.0.1 in the allow list.  I had a local application using "localhost" port 25 for outbound emails.

Comment: Just a note to anybody else who doesn't read carefully (like me) - it is IIS 6.0 Manager, not the newer more commonly used IIS 7.x Manager.  You won't find SMTP in the IIS7 tool.