# how to fix, "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1...."

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

Getting the following error message.

"Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 : Client host rejected: Message rejected: Undeliverable email received."

This is happening on a .net website hosted on windows 2003 server with IIS 6.0 after a form submission.

Comment: How would you fix that? If the mailbox is unavailable there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: i have followed every thing from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249100/iis-smtp-the-server-response-was-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-for-outgoing-address but still the issue remains

Comment: Yes, because you try to send a mail to an unavailable mailbox. This isn't a bug in the code...

Comment: The post you reference is when the server you're sending from doesn't allow relaying.  The error you have is that the client mail server is rejecting what you sent to it. I think they are different problems.

Comment: Are you saying that the smtp server is trying to send an email to an address which does not exist?

Comment: From the error message it either doesn't exist, or the destination server is outright *denying* the attempt to deliver to that particular mailbox.