# SMTP failed to relay message

Tags: c#, smtp

So i have this error. : [SMTP unable to relay message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249100/iis-smtp-the-server-response-was-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-for-outgoing-address)

Question : Can I see those failed message on the sender OUTBOX?
OR the relay failed already therefore wont reach that sender mailbox?

Comment: To send mail message you need to use a certified mail server.  So you need an account on a server.  Simply sending a mail message on the internet won't work.  Mail messages are secure so hacker won't be able to spoof email.  The failed messages are failing at the sender end to connect with a mail server.

Comment: Actually i just wanted to know if failed messages from smtp relay have reached at least the outbox of my sender mailbox

Comment: You should be able to see the failed message in the send box if the login passed to the account and the email address was valid format abc@def.ghi

Comment: Thanks, i really need this to defend that my code was working and the relay was the only issue