# Sending Email With System.Net.Mail

Tags: asp.net, email

I am trying to send a mail from admin@bitcoindk.dk to hejmeddig@gmail.com by doing this:

```
    MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage();
    mailObj.From = new MailAddress("admin@bit.dk");
    mailObj.To.Add("hejmeddig@gmail.com");
    mailObj.Body = "HEJ";
    mailObj.Subject = "HEJ";

    SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient();
    SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
```

In my web.config, i have this:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="admin@bitcoindk.dk">
        <network host="mail.bitcoindk.dk" port="25" userName="admin@bitcoindk.dk" password="password"  />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

When i send the mail, i get this exception

```
Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1 <hejmeddig@gmail.com>: Relay access denied
```

If i send a mail to admin@bit.dk, it works fine. But if i send to hejmeddig@gmail.com, or any other mail, i get the exception. I am using Uno Euro's mail service.

Comment: Is the mail exchange for itcoindk.dk on the same server this application is on?

Comment: No it is not the same server

Comment: You probably do not have the right to send email from server using the mail server.  Host typically do this to prevent the email being used as spam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong outgoing mail server.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to send emails.  See if something like this might help solve your problem.

```
SmtpSection cfg = NetSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/web.config")).MailSettings.Smtp;
MailMessage objMessage = new MailMessage();
objMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
objMessage.From = new MailAddress(cfg.From);
objMessage.Subject = "Some Subject";
objMessage.Body = sb.ToString();
objMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("google@gmail.com"));
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(cfg.Network.Host);
client.Send(objMessage);
```

Web.config

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp from="fromemail@mydomain.com">
         <network host="mail.mydomain.com" port="25" userName="mydomain.com" password="myPassword" />
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Try out what this guy did too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165721/mailbox-unavailable-the-server-response-was-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-for-abcxyz