# Programmatic emails triggering "The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, email, smtp

When I use outlook, I am able to send test email to my gmail address, however, when I do it from a console application it triggers : "The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay"

```
using System.Net.Mail;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("xxx@myCompany.com", "xxx@gmail.com");
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Port = 25;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Host = "xxx.xxx.com";
            mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
            mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
            client.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}
```

I verified that i have the correct client host through outlook. I also sent a test email to myself (from xx@mycompany to xx@mycompany) and that worked (although it sent it to the junk box). Why will it not let me send outgoing emails through this console app, but I can through the same address in outlook.

Comment: check similar questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165721/mailbox-unavailable-the-server-response-was-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-for-abcxyz

Comment: yea i did, that doesnt seem like the same issue to me, despite the same error message.

Comment: im sending TO a gmail account, wouldnt i need the local port of the smtp server?

Comment: @JacobAlley How do you know the email is actually failing? You are able to send to yourself, so that indicates that the email is actually successfully being sent. Have you checked the spam folder in the recipient account?

Comment: because the console app is throwing an exception and crashing the program, something it wasnt doing when i was able to send it to myself.

Comment: Ah, that seems to indicate an issue with the SMTP itself, not the code. try this? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jhoward/2005/10/11/resolving-smtp-error-550-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-for-userdomain-com-error-0x800ccc79/

Comment: @Equalsk this is a problem sending the email to another domain from exchange, not gmail.

Comment: @JacobAlley this might be better asked on ServerFault - check this thread http://serverfault.com/questions/476979/exchange-connector-wont-send-to-external-domains

Comment: Thanks man, i'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that if you have `client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;`, you need to set the credentials.  At least that is what I do:

```
 client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

 client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(someusername, somepassword);
```

edit:  I should clarify, `client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;`,  does not necessarily mean you need credentials listed, but if you are trying to send to an external domain (gmail.com), then your SMTP server will most likely require some type of SMTP Auth.

Comment: It depends - you don't necessarily need to provide credentials if the SMTP accepts anonymous connections. Besides, the emails send successfully to itself (indicating the connection to the SMTP is not the problem), just not to other domains. This seems to be a permissions error on the SMTP.

Comment: All emails sent to themselves will succeed if they are hosted on the same domain/server.  OP is trying to send to gmail.  I bet if he deleted his creds from outlook,  and tried to send to gmail, he would get the same error.

Comment: So you agree this answer probably won't help.

Comment: No I don't agree, because his issue is when he sends to an external domain in the console app.

Comment: he was right! lol thanks guys, i appreciate both of your help tremendously