# How to send mail (System.Net.Mail)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I tried to send email via c# by following:

```
  try {
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.To.Add("receiver@mail.com");
                message.Subject = "This is the Subject line";
                message.From = new MailAddress("sender@online.microsoft.com");
                message.Body = "This is the message body";
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver");
                smtp.Send(message);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
```

I get the error message:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver' at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream,
>   Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket,
>   Socket& abortSocket6) at......

I've never done this before. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use that URL then? Did you try looking up the SmtpClient documentation to see what that constructor parameter does?

Comment: That URL points to an XML document's *schema*. URLs aren't server addresses, they point to something on a server. A server address (web, email, FTP, whatever) is either an IP address or a fully qualified name.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx), the SmtpClient constructor takes a mail server host name as an argument, not a schema address. Try changing your argument to whatever SMTP server you will be using to send your email.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("my.mailserver.com");
```

Or, as CodeCaster pointed out, use the parameterless constructor which will then use your app or machine config settings instead (also detailed in the linked documentation)

Comment: Rather don't hardcode a sever address but use the parameterless constructor so the sever from your app's or machine's configuration will be used.

Comment: Fair point, edited accordingly

Comment: Thanks, I changed to a proper smtp host name. But now I get: " `System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at..`". Any idea what that means?

Comment: Sounds like relaying is disabled on your SMTP server. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165721/mailbox-unavailable-the-server-response-was-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-for-abcxyz