# Not able to send email from my asp.net application to different domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, smtp

I have developed asp.net application which sends email to the domain of my company. Example : ex@companydomain.com, but I'm not able to send it to any other domains, like ex@gmail.com or ex1@hotmail.com. Do I need to make changes in the smtp server or in my code? Please let me know. I'm pretty new to .net.Below is the code which I used :

```
        MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
        var MailResult = false;

        var EmailUser = RFSvc.Users.Where(u => u.Email == email).SingleOrDefault();
        if (EmailUser != null)
        {

            Msg.From = new MailAddress("noreply@example.com", "Company name");
            Msg.Subject = "Password Recovery";
            Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            Msg.Body = "Your User Name is: " + EmailUser.Username + "<br /> Your password is: " + EmailUser.Password;
            Msg.To.Add(email);

            SmtpClient MailClient = new SmtpClient();

            MailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            MailClient.Host = "mail.example.com";
            MailClient.Port = 25;
            MailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username","password");
            //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            MailClient.EnableSsl = false;

            try
            {
                MailClient.Send(Msg);

                MailResult = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326738/how-to-send-email-in-asp-net-c-sharp) to send mail in `.net`. Also gmail email ID should be like : example@gmail.com and not example@ex.gmail.com. It would help others to guide you, if you could post your code.

Comment: @stom thank you for reply. I have made the necessary edit to the question. I also got to know that my code is correct, and I need to do cofigurations in smtp server. Do you know what all configurations I need to do?

Comment: MailClient.EnableSsl = false;

Change to  MailClient.EnableSsl = True;

Answer (score 0):

Hey can you provide which port are you using ? so from that i can get more idea where you stuck

The Gmail SMTP server name is smtp.gmail.com and the port using send mail is 587 and also using NetworkCredential for password based authentication.

As [suggested by Trimantra Software Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail/41952779#41952779):

```
try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("to_address");
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
            mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Hope so it can helpful to you

Comment: Please Change this setting 

MailClient.EnableSsl = false;

Change to  MailClient.EnableSsl = True;

and also try if that port is not work then 587 default
and try to debug code

Comment: Hi @ILYAS, the code works fine. It sends the mail to my company domain. It just doesn't send to other domains. I think I need to configure the SMTP server. Do you know what configurations I need to do?

Comment: Also I have tried enabling SSL and changing he port to 587 it works but doesn't send to other domains

Comment: Are you sending mail from your domain ?? or google 

please can  your  configuration your Mail server  from your domain 

and if you use gmail to sending mail then it EnableSsl =true 
and if you sending from private domain  then made EnableSsl =False

Comment: Hi I'm sending with my mail server

Answer (score 0):

I am able to send mail from custom domain to gmail.com , Here is the code:

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("example@mydomain.com", "From Name");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("example@gmail.com", "To Name");
const string fromPassword = "password";
const string subject = "Subject";
const string body = "Body";            

MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);
message.Subject = subject;
message.Body = body;


var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
  Host = "smtp.mydomain.com",
  Port = 25,
  EnableSsl = true,
  DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
  UseDefaultCredentials = false,
  Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
  Timeout = 20000
};            

smtp.Send(message);
```

Note:

If it still doesn't work for you , contact your domain registrar or mail provider and get `smtp` mail settings , or try changing port 465 , 587 , or try commenting out single property of `SmtpClient`class at a time to check whether it works.

References:

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

[2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp)

Comment: What exactly didn't work ? did you get any error ? Do you have exception handling in place in your code ?

Comment: Hi @stom I tried sending mail to my company domain it works perfectly. But only when I try to send to other domain like google, yahoo it gives this exception :Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay

Comment: @SachinGotal , If you trying to send mail from site which is hosted in `IIS` then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165721/mailbox-unavailable-the-server-response-was-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-for-abcxyz) may help you.